# CopyFile() function causes exception while debugging but not while running from terminal

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Studio 2019 project, containing only one .cpp file, named as `copyFile.cpp`

```
#undef UNICODE

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    DWORD ret = CopyFile("xyz.txt", "xyzCopy.txt", FALSE);
    printf("\n\t ret: %d, getlasterror(): %d", ret, GetLastError());
    
    return 0;
}
```

There is a problem while debugging the code, stepping over this line:

```
DWORD ret = CopyFile("xyz.txt", "xyzCopy.txt", FALSE);
```

causes an exception to be thrown.

```
Exception thrown at 0x76E4B1AF (combase.dll) in copyFile.exe : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008
```

then the program breaks.

Meanwhile, `xyzCopy.txt` is being created, with a fresh new modify date but as an empty file, 0 KB.

On the other hand, if I run the .exe via terminal by `./copyFile.exe`, no exception is being thrown, and code execution continues to the below lines. The file `xyzCopy.txt` is being created, the content is full (not empty), however, the timestamp of creation is same as the original file. On contrast with the case while debugging.

Also, if `CopyFile()` fails, for example because of not being able to find the source file to be copied, the debugging works fine. So, the problem arises only if `CopyFile()` succeeds.

I have no idea what is the case. Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you explicitly call `CopyFileA` instead of the macro `CopyFile` does that change things?

Comment: Did you maybe activate compiler optimizations in the build that you are debugging? You should normally only use debug builds without compiler optimizations when using the debugger, otherwise the current line shown in the debugger may be misleading.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude nope, no difference.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel no, it is disabled, i checked. I also did not change any setting that came default by creating a c++ console project.

Comment: `#undef UNICODE` -- Why do you have this at the top of your source file?  If you don't want Unicode, go to the project settings and have the application built as MBCS, and get rid of the `#undef UNICODE`.  I wouldn't be the least bit surprise if that is causing the issue, as you're probably corrupting how `windows.h` will create certain internal structures and function definitions.

Comment: Have you seen this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/exception-thrown-on-64-bit-debugging/345554

Comment: Note that `GetLastError()` is not meaningful unless the most recent function call had an error (and is documented to set it). It also does not necessarily persist across function calls, so you need to save the value you're interested in immediately and then pass the saved value along. (That is, when `CopyFile` succeeds, both your calls to it can return pretty much anything. When it fails, only the first call is guaranteed to be related to that failure.)

Comment: Are you creating a "Debug" build or a "Release" build? Also, does it make any difference if you select the "Build->Rebuild Solution" option?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus program running? If so, is the same weird thing present without it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie did what you said, no difference. I also had tried this with W versions of functions, using wchar_t instead of plain char, no difference.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I was building Debug, not Release. I tried rebuild solution, no difference. For everyone trying to help, I wonder if you can reproduce the situation and face the same issue or not.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am not able to disable my antivirus program, I am in a secured corporation network. Administrator approval needed to disable it.

Comment: @muyustan: Your code works with me, except that I had to add `#include <string>` for the code to compile. I was able to step over the line with the `CopyFile` call using a debugger, without any exception occuring. The file was successfully copied. I didn't test the rest of your code. I am using MS Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The `GetLastErrorStdStr` can be dropped completely. You aren't using it in any meaningful way, so just get rid of it.

Comment: @muyustan: I also tend to think that it could be your virus scanner. Especially the link in one of the comments makes me think that this could be the reason. I guess the chance is about 30%. If possible, you may want to ask your system administrator to disable your virus scanner for 5 minutes, to see if that makes a difference. During that time, you could detach the network connection, in order to make it safe.

Comment: I don't see anything either. It's a simple API. Your error checking should be `if (ret == 0) { DWORD err = GetLastError(); cout << err; }`

Comment: @IInspectable fair enough, edited.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel OK, thank you for testing the code, I am out of office now (7 p.m in my timezone), tomorrow I will see if I could achieve deactivating the antivirus. But, it looks strange that antivirus does not cause any problem when the .exe is directly executed by command prompt, while it breaks if I do a VS debug.

Comment: @muyustan: Antivirus software and other security software often dig very deep into the system, and if they have a bug, very strange things can happen. I once determined that my antivirus software was the reason why I was experiencing certain bugs. Antivirus software is also known to cause trouble in quite a few games, too.

Comment: @SimonMourier ok, I had not looked what you have linked yesterday. Today i did, and the workaround suggested works well. It is kind of a bug then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find the root cause, however, @SimonMourier posted a [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/exception-thrown-on-64-bit-debugging/345554) in his comments, which suggest a workaround that works.

> Additional information: Toggling the debug option "Automatically close
> the console when debugging stops" on, stops the exception being
> thrown.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.